# How can I parse the emotes out of a Twitch IRC response into an list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, python-3.5, twitch

I would like to parse an IRC message from Twitch to a list of dictionaries, accounting for emotes.

Here is a sample of what I can get from Twitch:

```
"Testing. :) Confirmed!"

{"emotes": [(1, (9, 10))]}
```

It describes that there is the emote with ID 1 from characters 9 to 10 (with the string being zero-indexed).

I would like to have my data in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Testing. "
    },
    {
        "type": "emote",
        "text": ":)",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "text": " Confirmed!"
    }
]
```

Is there a relatively clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes there are, but nobody is going to code it for you. Try something and when you come with an error, ask a question

Comment: @iScrE4m I am not sure how to proceed, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your incoming message looks like this:

```
message = '''\
"Testing. :) Confirmed!"

{"emotes": [(1, (9, 10))]}'''
```

Or

```
text = "Testing. :) Confirmed!"
meta = '{"emotes": [(1, (9, 10))]}'
```

I'm going to assume it's the latter, because it's easy to convert from the former to the latter. It could also be that those are the python representations. You weren't very clear.

There's a *vastly* better way to approach this problem by not using regexes and just using string parsing:

```
import json                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

text = 'Testing. :) Confirmed! :P'                                                                                                                                                                                              
print(len(text))                                                                                                                                                                                                                
meta = '{"emotes": [(1, (9, 10)), (2, (23,25))]}'                                                                                                                                                                               
meta = json.loads(meta.replace('(', '[').replace(')', ']'))                                                                                                                                                                     


results = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
cur_index = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
for emote in meta['emotes']:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    results.append({'type': 'text', 'text': text[cur_index:emote[1][0]]})                                                                                                                                                       
    results.append({'type': 'emote', 'text': text[emote[1][0]:emote[1][1]+1],                                                                                                                                                   
                    'id': emote[0]})                                                                                                                                                                                            
    cur_index = emote[1][1]+1                                                                                                                                                                                                   

if text[cur_index:]:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    results.append({'type': 'text', 'text': text[cur_index:]})                                                                                                                                                                  

import pprint; pprint.pprint(results)
```

---

From your comment, the data comes in a custom format. There were a couple of characters that I copy/pasted from the comment that I'm not sure *actually* show up in the incoming data, I hope I got that part right. There was also only one type of emote in the message so I'm not entirely sure how it denotes multiple different emote types - I'm hoping that there's some separator and not multiple `emote=` sections, or this approach needs some heavy modifications, but this *should* provide the parsing without the need for regex.

```
from collections import namedtuple


Emote = namedtuple('Emote', ('id', 'start', 'end'))


def parse_emotes(raw):
    emotes = []
    for raw_emote in raw.split('/'):
        id, locations = raw_emote.split(':')
        id = int(id)
        locations = [location.split('-')
                     for location in locations.split(',')]
        for location in locations:
            emote = Emote(id=id, start=int(location[0]), end=int(location[1]))
            emotes.append(emote)
    return emotes

data = r'@badges=moderator/1;color=#0000FF;display-name=2Cubed;emotes=25:6-10,12-16;id=05aada01-f8c1-4b2e-a5be-2534096057b9;mod=1;room-id=82607708;subscriber=0;turbo=0;user-id=54561464;user-type=mod:2cubed!2cubed@2cubed.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #innectic :Hiya! Kappa Kappa'

meta, msgtype, channel, message = data.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
meta = dict(tag.split('=') for tag in meta.split(';'))
meta['emotes'] = parse_emotes(meta['emotes'])
```

Comment: Twitch packets come in a custom format, as follows. `r"@badges=moderator/1;color=#0000FF;display-name=2Cubed;emotes=25:6-10,12-16;id=05aada01-f8c1-4b2e-a5be-2534096057b9;mod=1;room-id=82607708;subscriber=0;turbo=0;user-id=54561464;user-type=mod :2cubed!2cubed@2cubed.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #innectic :Hiya! Kappa Kappa"` Unfortunately, some regex is required to parse the message body and emote locations out. After that parsing is done, though, I quite like your solution. :)

Comment: @2Cubed I've updated my answer to show that you probably don't actually need regex for parsing *those* messages either ;) Even if there are multiple types of packets such that the `split` part will fail, you can probably just use `' PRIVMSG ' in data`.

Comment: This looks fantastic. It seems to fail, though, when multiple different emotes are used, such as in this packet. `r"@badges=moderator/1;color=#0000FF;display-name=2Cubed;emotes=25:8-12/70433:14-22;id=20574cd9-a008-4b03-bc1b-80fabcd0723f;mod=1;room-id=82607708;subscriber=0;turbo=0;user-id=54561464;user-type= :2cubed!2cubed@2cubed.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #innectic :Test... Kappa KappaRoss"`. I submitted an edit which fixes this.

Comment: `/` - that was it. Just replace `xxx` with `/` and I believe that ought to work. (I was using `xxx` as a placeholder because I didn't know what they used)

Comment: Ah, cool. This seems to work perfectly, and is infinitely cleaner than what I had before. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Just remember - Python has *really* powerful string processing tools. Very rarely do you need to reach for regular expressions - I've actually only used them in a couple of cases over 8 years. Sure, regexes can be useful, but usually they're overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which, although quite ugly, works.

```
import re

packet_expression = re.compile(r'(@.+)? :([a-zA-Z0-9][\w]{2,23})!\2@\2.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #([a-zA-Z0-9][\w]{2,23}) :(.+)')

def parse_twitch(packet):

    match = re.match(packet_expression, packet)

    items = match.group(1)[1:].split(';')
    tags = dict(item.split('=') for item in items)

    emote_expression = re.compile(r'(\d+):((\d+-\d+,)*\d+-\d+)')
    tags["emotes"] = [
        (int(emotes[0]), (int(start), int(end)))
        for emotes in re.findall(emote_expression, tags.get("emotes", ''))
        for location in emotes[1].split(',')
        for start, end in [location.split('-')]
    ]

    message = match.group(4)
    characters = list(message)

    offset = 0
    for emote in tags["emotes"]:
        characters[emote[1][0]-offset : emote[1][1]-offset+1] = [{
            "type": "emote",
            "text": ''.join(characters[emote[1][0]-offset : emote[1][1]-offset+1]),
            "id": emote[0]
        }]
        offset += emote[1][1] - emote[1][0]

    index = 0
    while any(isinstance(item, str) for item in characters):
        if isinstance(characters[index], str) and isinstance(characters[index+1], str):
            characters[index:index+2] = [characters[index] + characters[index+1]]
        else:
            if isinstance(characters[index], str):
                characters[index] = {"type": "text", "text": characters[index]}
            index += 1

    return characters
```